# Store output as text, not list

Tags: python, list, text, random

I am generating text using this :

```
for i in xrange(100):
    sys.stdout.write(alphabet[bisect.bisect(f_list, random.random()) - 1])
```

i get output that looks like this:

```
fnhtlr hhub  del tn eleo s d  nerowepeldhoantah yf  tr e saetenwgkoyears 
oenooe urbmhonnrniwc iasseb
```

and I would like to know how to store the output as TEXT, not a list, so that i can use fd.inc(word) on it. I am basically trying to plot Zipf's law with my random output.

if I use this :

```
text1 = [alphabet[bisect.bisect(f_list, random.random())] for i in xrange(300)]
```

my output is stored as a list and fd doesn't work on it, as it considers each character to be a separate word.

```
for word in text1:
    fd.inc(word)
print fd
<FreqDist: ' ': 1776, 'e': 1008, 'a': 752, 't': 750, 'n': 604, 'i': 586,
 'o': 556, 'h': 542, 's': 528, 'r': 478, 'l': 388, 'd': 312, 'u': 242, 
'm': 202, 'w': 192, 'g': 172, 'b': 152, 'p': 152, 'f': 150, 'c': 148, 'y': 120,
 'k': 90, 'v': 66, 'q': 12, 'z': 10, 'x': 8, 'j': 4>
```

I would like each sequence of letters separated by a space to be considered as a word, i.e. for the output to be considered as text.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: When you say "text" I believe you mean "string" :)

Comment: What is `fd.inc`? For that matter, what are `alphabet` and `f_list`?

Comment: sorry let me be more precise : alphabet is string.lowercase + ' ', f_list is the cumulative frequency of letters and whitespace that i found in Moby Dick. then i generate a random number, which is matched to f_list, which in turn gives me a "random" letter. this is how i get my "random" text, from the frequencies of letters and whitespace in moby dick. f_list = [0, 0.068, 0.083, 0.103 etc...]

Comment: and 
`fd=FreqDist()`
`for word in text1:`
    `fd.inc(word)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
text1 = ' '.join([alphabet[bisect.bisect(f_list, random.random())] for i in xrange(300)])
```

As to add more detail: `' '.join(list)` is the pythonic way of joining a list to a string. The `' '`-part says that it should be joined with a whitespace. If you for example would join it with a comma it would be `','` instead.

Or you could even skip the brackets like this:

```
text1 = ' '.join(alphabet[bisect.bisect(f_list, random.random())] for i in xrange(300))
```

Maybe you want to join the list completly without anything between the charachters. In that case the solution is using join like this:

```
text1 = ''.join([alphabet[bisect.bisect(f_list, random.random())] for i in xrange(300)])
```

One more thing thought. What happens if you change your last sample snippet in your question to:

```
for word in text1.split():
    fd.inc(word)
print fd
```

This will split again after joining, but this time it will split on word and not characters (so keep the join also).

## Final word

Since the issue has been solved I want to just explain what those things mean:

`''.join(list)` - This means taking the original list which is separated by every charachter and make a string out of it.

`string.split()` - This means to make a list of it again (which fd.inc whatever that is apperently want one) but make this one separated by word and not charachter like the original list.

Also, I would recommend you looking on some Python basics which will help you in the future :) This is a great series of videos: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKTZoB2Vjuk

Comment: Thank you, however it seems that ' '.join just changes the output, adding an extra whitespace between each letter. this is what i get :
 `p   t t n g c d   e n s w r o e   a s l e r   n   h e e   t a u i   h t n r n r   b s a o t e t n   t t t d   a m t p o t   e a s i g g a t t n w y   s t n r o o t i p   e a g g e e c d l b s w u r   n t h r t   r k t   w e p l a a c h o   p o r i n i r h b d t t   m w h o h a n u   t d e   n   h a p i     a n   r e k e o       i n i s e t   a a a l n   t   t t   h s d   a`

Comment: and the frequency distribution is unchanged, it still only considers letters instead of words like i would want it to... : 
`<FreqDist: ' ': 714, 't': 60, 'a': 50, 'e': 48, 'n': 46, 'r': 34, 'i': 32, 'o': 30, 'h': 28, 's': 24, 'g': 18, 'd': 16, 'p': 16, 'w': 14, 'b': 12, 'l': 12, 'u': 10, 'c': 8, 'f': 6, 'k': 6, 'm': 6, 'v': 6, 'y': 2>` and now the frequency of the space is much higher.

Comment: Added a new sample above. But if the list not containg any whitespace elements there will only be one word totally? Anyway, check out my third sample and see if it does what you want.

Comment: yes absolutely, ''.join is the output i need. But i am still stuck : if my output looks like this : `doshe eiotboq stt u r cblnstbaeroeleebptn tarde pgb t tnonc sieherhriieee n teuethhwma bd i ut` than fd['stt'] returns 0 when i would like it to pick up that 'set' is a **word** that appears once in the text. I hope i'm being clear... i can't seem to find a solution as to how to solve this problem :/

Comment: ''.join keeps the whitespaces that were generated, so it is fine

Comment: Well, I know nothing about the libraries you use nor the rest of your code. So I think you have to go back and read the manual and the samples again... Sorry.

Comment: Got one more solution for you to try above :)

Comment: Try to use `''.join(...)`, without the space between the quotation marks. It return the string without adding any additional space inserted.

Comment: yes thanks @gianluca, using ''.join and text1.split(' ') has solved the problem. Merci!

Comment: @Julia: there are [many newline symbols `'\n'` in the Moby Dick](https://gist.github.com/48798f102d1a593eb77a) therefore `text.split()` should be used instead of `text.split(' ')` to get words.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Tottaly agreed. Overlooked that :)